# Is there any way I could simplify this code using more generics?

Tags: c#

I've tried to simplify this but can't think of a way to make it simpler. There are a lot more of these rows with one for every table I access. Any suggestions?

```
public static IAzureTable<Sequence> GetSequenceTable(string datastoreValue)
{
    var sequenceTable = new AzureTable<Sequence>(GetStorageAccount(datastoreValue), "Sequences");
    return (sequenceTable);
}
public static IAzureTable<Topic> GetTopicTable(string datastoreValue)
{
    var topicTable = new AzureTable<Topic>(GetStorageAccount(datastoreValue), "Topics");
    return (topicTable);
}
public static IAzureTable<Test> GetTestTable(string datastoreValue)
{
    var testTable = new AzureTable<Test>(GetStorageAccount(datastoreValue), "Tests");
    return (testTable);
}
```

Here's more for reference. Not really wanting to change this but I could add to it:

```
 public class AzureTable<T> : AzureTableBase<T>, IInitializer where T : TableServiceEntity
    {

        public AzureTable()
            : this(CloudConfiguration.GetStorageAccount())
        {
        }

        public AzureTable(CloudStorageAccount account)
            : this(account, null)
        {
        }

        public AzureTable(CloudStorageAccount account, string tableName)
            : base(account, tableName)
        {
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would remove repitition of the GetTable family of methods:

```
public static IAzureTable<T> GetTable<T>(string datastoreValue, string tableName) where T : TableServiceEntity    
{    
     return new AzureTable<T>(GetStorageAccount(datastoreValue), tableName);    
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
var table = GetTable<Sequence>("DatastoreName", "Sequences");
```

Comment: what does GetTable<Test>(datastoreValue, "Topics") return in this case?

Comment: They type 'T' must be convertible to Microsoft.WindowsAzureStorageClient.TableServiceEntity in order to use it as a parameter'T' in the generic class 'AzureToolket.AzureTable<T>'   This error appears as a red underline for <T> on the line with the return.

Comment: I added the missing type parameter constraint. @Caspar Kleijne obviously it would go bang if you give it bad combinations, I was about to suggest creating a factory class using a dictionary to map types to table names, but others have already done so.

Comment: @Robert: it lacks generic type restiriction (where T: ...)

Answer (score 0):

you could use [**optional parameters**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) (C# 4.0) to combine the last 2:

```
public AzureTable(CloudStorageAccount account, string tableName = null)
            : base(account, tableName)
        {
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the same as Alex Peck's answer, but with a little more machinery so you only specify the table name and type in a single place (less error prone).

```
public class TableSpec<T>
{
  public readonly string name;
  public TableSpec(string name) { this.name = name; }
}

public static readonly TableSpec<Sequence> SequenceTableSpec = new TableSpec<Sequence>("Sequences");
public static readonly TableSpec<Topic> TopicTableSpec = new TableSpec<Topic>("Topics");
public static readonly TableSpec<Test> TestTableSpec = new TableSpec<Test>("Tests");

public static IAzureTable<T> GetTable<T>(TableSpec<T> spec, string datastoreValue)
{
  var table = new AzureTable<T>(GetStorageAccount(datastoreValue), spec.name);
  return table;
}
```

Example usage:

```
var topicTable = GetTable(TopicTableSpec, datastoreValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static Dictionary<Type, string> _tableNames = new Dictionary<Type, string>
{
    {typeof(Sequence), "Sequences"},
    {typeof(Account), "Accounts"},
    {typeof(Test), "Tests"}
}

public static IAzureTable<T> GetTable(string datastorevalue) where T: Microsoft.WindowsAzureStorageClient.TableServiceEntity
{
    return new AzureTable<T>(GetStorageAccount(datastoreValue), _tableNames[typeof(T)]);
}
```

Comment: All these methods are giving the same syntax error: They type 'T' must be convertible to Microsoft.WindowsAzureStorageClient.TableServiceEntity in order to use it as a parameter'T' in the generic class 'AzureToolket.AzureTable<T>' This error appears as a red underline for <T> on the line with the return.

Comment: @Robert Dawson: Updated answer, added `where` type restriction.

Answer (score -1):

Or, you could just do

```
    public static IAzureTable<T> GetTable<T>(string datastoreValue, string tableName = null) where T : TableServiceEntity
    {
        var pluralizationService = PluralizationService.CreateService(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
        tableName = tableName ?? pluralizationService.Pluralize(typeof(T).Name);
        return new AzureTable<T>(GetStorageAccount(datastoreValue), tableName);
    }
```

This uses the .NET 4.0 pluralization service.

Comment: I would really like to know why this answer was downvoted. It solves the problem. In the general case it allows magic to figure out the table, name - but when that magic is insufficient you can override it. This is how most of todays frameworks are built (think Asp.NET MVC), and there's no type purity when you are providing strings as parameters anyway.

Comment: Not downvoted by me. There was also another answer downvoted by somebody.